# Decompose an ISO8601 format time stamp with regular expressions

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to extract the minutes and seconds from an time stamp of `ISO8601` format. I made some tries with `regexp` but I have no experience on that.

Could you please help me on this?

Examples:

- PT1M46S --> 1 minute, 46 seconds
- PT36S --> 36 seconds

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getPart = @(str, c) str2double(['0' regexp(str, ['\d*(?=' c ')'], 'match', 'once')]);

str = 'PT36S'; 
seconds = getPart(str, 'S');
minutes = getPart(str, 'M');
hours   = getPart(str, 'H');
```

This looks for character `c`, finds the digits behind it and converts them to a double. It adds character `'0'` in the beginning because if `regexp` can't find a match it returns an empty string. Adding this converts empty strings to zero while not affecting other numbers. If you want to restrict it to the parts after `PT`, you can remove that from original string using

```
str = regexprep(str, '^.*PT', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use datevec to turn strings representing hours, minutes etc into corresponding numeric values. See "help datestr" to understand rules for symbols used in second input to datevec, ie. the format string. Here's how you can convert the two examples given, I leave it to you to extend it to cover the entire format.

```
str = 'PT36S';
str = strrep(str, 'PT', ''); % PT have to go. 
if ~ismember('M', str)
% To use a single format string, we must write zero minutes if none are there already
str = ['00M', str];
end

% Date string cannot contain characters y,m,d,H,M or S, so remove these
str = strrep(str, 'S', ' ');
str = strrep(str, 'M', ' ');

% Call datevec with appropriate format string
[~, ~, ~, ~, min, sec] = datevec(str, 'MM SS')
```

You can extend this to manage hours, days etc by including additional if loops similar to that above. I am not familiar with this standard beyond the examples given so let me know if it's not as simple as that.